# Important data is visible on html page sources if sent to a function by ejs

Tags: html, ejs

I am having an issue that if send data to a function by ejs it is easily visible in page source. Does this can cause security risk?

Eg. of code

```
<a onclick="editDetail('<%=JSON.stringify(data[i])%>')">Edit</a>
```

On page source :

```
<a  href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong" onclick="editUser('{&#34;type&#34;:&#34;customer&#34;,&#34;notification_status&#34;:&#34;1&#34;,&#34;wallet_balance&#34;:&#34;500&#34;,&#34;block_status&#34;:&#34;0&#34;,&#34;_id&#34;:&#34;5b1fc76bf04810496b7cf149&#34;,&#34;name&#34;:&#34;Omeesh&#34;,&#34;email&#34;:&#34;omeesh@relinns.com&#34;,&#34;contact&#34;:78371724568,&#34;password&#34;:&#34;$2a$10$afc1Ei.z0PZ2sWsX7Mbwd.EYliwVa48cIFuLqwcupnIdvEfhy79AS&#34;,&#34;device_token&#34;:&#34;cmtl5S48n6w:APA91bFlX71jrg2xKcZym3upHIvY8uGraTbXI9clBKh_Cu2LydPodY2TuPfVaFXMNiWF5ZeDF7TfgV6Svyz6BY5xDJ7iWXgwWOT7aHZe6NwutKsdOJJZO1WGSKC7y5V0UGTiLFp-kIPX&#34;,&#34;platform&#34;:&#34;1&#34;,&#34;__v&#34;:0,&#34;socket&#34;:&#34;Zh3Vb46deerhDGu4AAAn&#34;,&#34;notification_id&#34;:&#34;cmtl5S48n6w:APA91bFlX71jrg2xKcZym3upHIvY8uGraTbXI9clBKh_Cu2LydPodY2TuPfVaFXMNiWF5ZeDF7TfgV6Svyz6BY5xDJ7iWXgwWOT7aHZe6NwutKsdOJJZO1WGSKC7y5V0UGTiLFp-kIPX&#34;}');">Edit</a>
```

**What can i do here, so that all this data is not visible. Or is it just okay, it works like this only?**

Comment: Remove equal sign = from this part <%=JSON.stringify(data[i])%>, it should not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are rendering the complete object instead of the value you need. For suppose if you only need id you should display id by using

```
<%=JSON.stringify(data[i].id)%>
```

or

```
<%=JSON.stringify(data[i].customer)%>
```